# Cross Validation, scikit-learn, parallel is slower

Tags: python, pydev, scikit-learn

I am learning how to use scikit-learn.

When testing the [cross validation function](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/statistical_inference/model_selection.html), if I turn on parallel computing using

```
cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc, X_digits, y_digits, cv=kfold, n_jobs=-1)
```

the result is a lot slower than if I turn it off using

```
cross_validation.cross_val_score(svc, X_digits, y_digits, cv=kfold, n_jobs=1)
```

How can I stop this?

I am using PyDev, Anacondas 3.3 on a 64bit Windows 7 machine.  From looking at Task Manager, it appears that the performance hit is caused by many instances of Python being started and stopped.  Why do they not start, and stay started?

Comment: Your data might not be big enough to overcome the overhead of parallelization.

Comment: That might be the case, but if so the parallelisation is very poor, as I run a similar script in Matlab and the performance hit is not nearly as bad.  I am hoping that the problem is due to my poor understanding of the tool, rather than the tool being unsuitable for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

> Why do they not start, and stay started?

Because that's not how the `multiprocessing` module in Python works at present, and that's what scikit-learn uses internally. In Python 3.4, this will be fixed at least for POSIX (Linux, Mac OS X) platforms. I don't believe the CPython developers also intend to fix this for Windows. Light-weight parallel processing for scikit-learn is [in the works](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/2528), but a release is still some time away.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using accelerated implementations of algorithms - such as scikit-learn-intelex - https://github.com/intel/scikit-learn-intelex

For SVM you for sure would be able to get higher compute efficiency, however for such large datasets this still would be noticeable.

First install package

```sh
pip install scikit-learn-intelex
```

And then add in your python script

```py
from sklearnex import patch_sklearn
patch_sklearn()
```